# Adding label text together

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, expression

Hi im relatively new to iOS and I'm just wondering how i would add two labels together.

```
- (IBAction)switch1
{    
    if (switch1.on) {
        value1.text = @"3";
    } else {
        value1.text = @"0";
    }
}

- (IBAction)switch2
{
    if (switch2.on) {
        value2.text = @"3";
    } else {
        value2.text = @"0";
    }
}
```

As you can see i have used two switches which would show two different values if they were turned on or off.

Could someone help me understand how i would add two values together.

I.e if switch one was on and switch two was off the value would be three i want this value to be shown in another label.

So far i have come up with this but for some reason it doesn't work, i have a feeling it is the format specifier but I'm not sure.

```
int sum = [[value1 text] intValue] + [[value2 text] intValue];
value3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
```

Comment: is var sum has the value or 0?

Comment: what the result u get in "sum"

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the value3 field is empty

Comment: When are you running that code? Please add more to the question to show the scope of when each bit of code runs.

Comment: have u checked in value1 and value2 has values before the concordinate

Comment: Please take some time to investigate the MVC design pattern.  You should be holding the data you want to work on using `int`s and only displaying the values within the `UILabel` objects (and not using them as data storage as you suggest).  The question should not be "Adding label text together" but rather "How to display the results of a calculation within a label", which when you say it sounds simple, and that's cos it is.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes i have

Comment: just try that select both switches value and check that what the result u get in sum

Comment: the sum comes up as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont you have this:

```
int sum = [[value1 text] intValue] + [[value2 text] intValue];
value3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sum];
```

in ViewDidLoad or something? Because you have to call this at the end of both IBActions. If you don't, your final value will never change.

Comment: Np we all pass through it ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you properly created an **outlet connection** in Interface Builder as described here:

   [Creating an Outlet Connection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingOutlet.html)

   In short words. Ctrl+Click & Drag from the UISwitch to File’s Owner and click the new `switch1` or `switch2` action. Create outlets for the text fields and switches and link them.
2. Set breakpoints in `switch1` and `switch2` methods and ensure there are being called.
3. Use `po` command in the console to check if the text fields and switches are configured correctly.

   For example:

   ```
   po _textField1
   ```

   should print text field's description. It will print `nil` when the text field is not there - not linked to a control in interface builder.

Comment: First set a breakpoint. Then, when it's hit and the execution of the app pauses, use the po command to print information about the text fields.

Comment: there labels when i using the po command it says error po_value1 is not a valid command

Comment: You are missing a space character after `po`. That's why compiler complains. Type `po _value1` and it should work.